# Is there a way to have a dropdown combo in an asp.net mvc site with images instead of text?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, combobox

Is there any way to have a combobox of images instead of text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you using jQuery along with special plugin http://plugins.jquery.com/project/image-combobox